# Sublime Text 3 Is using wrong path

Tags: c, gcc, sublimetext3

Im trying to compile `C` code in Sublime text editor.

In sublime I went into Tools->Build Systems->New Build System. And pasted in.

```
}
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

My environmental variable `path` is following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;C:\MinGW\bin
```

When I try to compile my C code, the output is:

```
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['gcc', 'test.c', '-o', 'test.exe', '&&', 'test.exe']]
[dir: C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\prog\C]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin]
```

Why is my path wrong? Why did I get an exit code of 1? How should I do?

Comment: You must use `shell_cmd` or `"shell": true` if you use shell commands like `&&`.

Comment: @r-stein But I am declaring `"shell": true`

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that. You have defined the path as system variable not as user variable?

Comment: @r-stein Yeah, I think so atleast. Right click My computer, properties, advanced system properties, environmental variables, system variables. And there I select path.

Comment: There are two panels the upper one for user variables and the lower one for system variables. If you open the `cmd.exe` and type `echo %PATH%` it also has the wrong path?

Comment: @r-stein It has the correct path there as well. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;C:\MinGW\bin`. Alright, tried again. It seems to work now. No Idea why it didnt before. Thx!